# Trying to make Thinkglink work with Impress.js

Tags: jquery, impress.js

I'm trying to embed http://www.thinglink.com/ images (meant to be 'dynamic' - able to have 'hotspots' for video, audio for still images)  within Impress.js : http://bartaz.github.com/impress.js/#/bored

When working correctly, it should look and behave this way: http://3bute.com/

The problem: In impress.js, when you click on a 'hotspot' on the embedded thinglink image, control for embedded asset gets lost.

If I get this resolved, it would be a great platform for graphic journalists like myself in presenting interactive and dynamic stories.

Any assistance is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

The problem comes from a couple of lines in the sample CSS supplied with impress.js that makes the body unclickable.

If you remove:

```
.impress-enabled          { pointer-events: none }
.impress-enabled #impress { pointer-events: auto }
```

All should work with Thinglink!

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "control for embedded asset gets lost"? Do you mean that links open in some other window or something else?

To investigate this further, could you provide:

1. Address to a web page where the problem can be seen
2. Steps to recreate the problem
3. What would be your expected outcome and what happens currently?

Comment: When working correctly, it should look and behave this way: http://3bute.com/ but this is a static site. When Thinglink is embedded in impress.js, the video component sticks, you can't close video window or control (play,pause) video.

Comment: I tested this out and there seem to be some issues with Thinglink + Impress.js. I'll add a ticket on this to the Thinglink issue list. Unfortunately, I cannot currently promise any due date for fixing the issue.